# server the /tmp/ directory as /npm-logs using Nginx webserver

Tags: nginx, browser, directory, centos, webserver

I wish to expose the `/tmp/` directory as `/npm-logs` in Nginx

I wish to serve the contents of `/tmp` directory by hitting this URL: `https://portal.sggs.com.au/npm-logs`

Below is what the server block looks like:

```
    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name _;
        ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.sggs.com.au/fullchain.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.sggs.com.au/privkey.pem";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;


        location /npm-logs/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /tmp/;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
        }

        location / {
    alias /var/www/SGGS/SGGS_PROD_UI/build/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
       }
  }
```

The `/var/www/logs/nginx/error.log` does not log anything.

The nginx `access.log` gets the below entry:

```
103.97.96.31 - - [06/Sep/2023:19:30:04 +0000] "GET /npm-logs HTTP/2.0" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Below is the directory permissions:

```
[Wed Sep 06 19:34:46 root@SGGS-Prod:/var/www/SGGS/SGGS_PROD_API ] $ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. 7 root root 4096 Sep  6 19:33 /tmp
```

Below is the nginx process:

```
[Wed Sep 06 19:34:52 root@SGGS-Prod:/var/www/SGGS/SGGS_PROD_API ] $ ps -ef | grep nginx
root      603490       1  0 19:29 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx     603491  603490  0 19:29 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     603492  603490  0 19:29 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root      603534  603173  0 19:32 pts/1    00:00:00 vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I restarted nginx several times to make sure the above changes are reflected.

Below is the snapshot of the browser when trying to access the directory.

[image]

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed `location /npm-logs/ {` to `location /npm-logs {` and it worked. The trailing `/` was casing it to fail.